# Bind datagrid to an ObservableCollection from an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I looked on the net to find the answer, but didn't found exactly what I am looking for.
This question helped me a lot [WPF DataGrid: Binding a Collection Property to Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266821/wpf-datagrid-binding-a-collection-property-to-column)

But I am looking to show the "Name" of the personne and the multiple Smartphones she get.

```
Person's Name1

  Smartphone1  manufacturer    other details
  Smartphone2  manufacturer    other details
Person's Name2

  Smartphone1  manufacturer    other details
  Smartphone2  manufacturer    other details
```

How could I modify in this post to get the right solution?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where it's failing in order for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have written is how you want it to be formatted, rather then just the data structure then look at [How to: Group, sort, and filter data in the DataGrid control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's technically possible to embed one grid inside a cell of another, this type of user interface gets messy very fast.

I'd suggest using a TreeView control instead - ideal for this type of nested data, and using data templates you can design different U.I. layouts for Person and Phone elements.